# TX buffer of ttyS

Tags: linux

I am writing a program in C, but I have no idea how I can check the output buffer for ttyS.
I would like to know how many characters I can yet write to it or if the trasmitter in that moment still  working

Answer (score 1):

Most serial drivers support

```
int  count = 0;
ioctl (fd, TIOCOUTQ, &count);
```

where `TIOCOUTQ` returns the number of characters in the output buffer.  It does not make much sense to find out how many bytes can be written since most Linux serial drivers will dynamically allocate buffer space as needed.

See the [`tty_ioctl` summary](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl).

Comment: I think you've misread it (probably due to the slightly dodgy formatting of that page) and actually mean `TIOCOUTQ`.